# Is there a way to link a page that's a local file with href?

Tags: html

I'm a pretty new coder and, I don't know much about HTML5 so, I couldn't find a tutorial on how to do it.
(I'm working on a study helper app and since I didn't set up a website yet, I can't link a page with a URL.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, using relative file paths this is very possible. A relative file path points to a file relative to the current page. An example of this would be `href="document.html"`. This dictates that document.html is in the same folder as the current webpage. Further examples of these are available on this
[webpage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp).